# Java + raspberry program about loop with specific time

Tags: java, netbeans, raspberry-pi

So first of all I'm quite new to Java. At college we are programming using raspberry pi 3 and Java NetBeans.

I have to make traffic lights. The traffic lights should work in normal mode for 2 minutes and 30 seconds. Then it should switch to blinking yellow light which should work for 1 minute and after that it should shut down. There are no specific times for every light in normal mode. I have to written this code in those time frames which I wrote above:

```
// Normal mode for 2 minutes 30 seconds

red.on();

Thread.sleep(1000);

red.off();

Thread.sleep(100);

yellow.on();

Thread.sleep(1000);

yellow.off();

Thread.sleep(1000);

green.on();

Thread.sleep(1000);

green.off();

Thread.sleep(1000);

// Only yellow blinking for 1 minute

yellow.on();

Thread.sleep(1000);

yellow.off();

Thread.sleep(1000);

//Shutdown after 1 minute of yellow blinking

red.off();

yellow.off();

green.off();
```

How do I put those modes in those time frames? I thought that I could use `for` loop for them but don't know how to set the correct time, maybe any other options or anyone could make it with `for` loop?

Sorry if some sentences are wrong, because English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop.

```
// Normal mode for 2 minutes 30 seconds

int pauseTime = 1000
int normalElapsedTime = 0
int blinkingElapsedTime = 0

while (normalElapsedTime < (60000*2.5))
{
red.on();
Thread.sleep(pauseTime);
normalElapsedTime = normalElapsedTime  + pauseTime;

red.off();
Thread.sleep(pauseTime);
normalElapsedTime = normalElapsedTime  + pauseTime;

yellow.on();
Thread.sleep(pauseTime);
normalElapsedTime = normalElapsedTime  + pauseTime;

yellow.off();
Thread.sleep(pauseTime);
normalElapsedTime = normalElapsedTime  + pauseTime;

green.on();
Thread.sleep(pauseTime);
normalElapsedTime = normalElapsedTime  + pauseTime;

green.off();
Thread.sleep(pauseTime);
normalElapsedTime = normalElapsedTime  + pauseTime;
} //end while

// Only yellow blinking for 1 minute

while (blinkingElapsedTime < (60000*1))
{
yellow.on();
Thread.sleep(pauseTime);
blinkingElapsedTime = blinkingElapsedTime + pauseTime;

yellow.off();
Thread.sleep(pauseTime);
blinkingElapsedTime = blinkingElapsedTime + pauseTime;
} //end while

//Shutdown after 1 minute of yellow blinking

red.off();
yellow.off();
green.off();
```